# Passing levels to predict randomForest with a raster

Tags: r, geospatial, random-forest, r-raster

I try to predict forest stand types (n=43 classes coding
landform, geology, water- and nutrient supply etc.)
on a large 1027206000 cell raster by randomForests.

Among many DEM derived parameters that I am using as covariates, I also have 2 rasters with ID numbers of a geological map and a soil map. Many categorical mapping units go with those IDs. I train the models with a dataframe and attach the categorical mapping units by "merge" to it.

So far everything is ok. The model does what it should do and I
can predict some test data held in a dataframe too.

But now I intent to make some maps of the predictions.
But when running the model with a rasterstack or brick
gives only rasters with all NA's. My impression is,
that I do something wrong in passing the factor levels to the rasterstack/rasterbrick.

Her is some code that reproduces the problem.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(randomForest)

# make a raster
set.seed(0)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)) * 10
is.factor(r)
r <- round(r)

# make faktor
f <- as.factor(r)
is.factor(f)

# get some none-sense levels
x <- levels(f)[[1]]
x$code <- paste("A",letters[10:20])
x$code2 <- paste("B",letters[10:20])
x$code3 <- letters[10:20]

levels(f) <- x
f<-deratify(f) # make a brick
levels(f)


set.seed(2)
# get some none-sense dataframe
xx<-data.frame(code=sample(rep(paste("A",letters[10:20]),10)),
               code2=sample(rep(paste("B",letters[10:20]),10)),
               code3=rep( letters[10:20],10),
               y=as.factor(sample(rep(paste(rep(1:5)),22))))

# fit and predict a random forest with it
ranfor<-randomForest(y~.,data=xx,ntree=100)
predict(ranfor)

# try to predict with a raster
names(f)<-c("code","code2","code3")
a<-predict(object=f,ranfor,na.omit=T,factors=list(code=levels(xx$code),
            code2=levels(xx$code2),
            code3=levels(xx$code3)))

plot(a) # gives an empty raster

# convert the raster to a dataframe and predict again
x<-as.data.frame(f)
names(x)<-c("code","code2","code3")
aa<-predict(ranfor,x)

plot(aa) # works just fine!
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages: [1] randomForest_4.6-10 rasterVis_0.35      latticeExtra_0.6-26 RColorBrewer_1.1-2  lattice_0.20-33     raster_2.4-15       sp_1.1-1           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] grid_3.1.2    hexbin_1.27.0 Rcpp_0.11.6   rgdal_1.0-4   tools_3.1.2   zoo_1.7-12
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problems, I created rasters of all categorical variables after I recoded the factors levels from character strings to "numeric" levels . Then predict:raster does the job. However, that is a pretty poor solution to the problem. So still: any help is greatly appreciated!